# Remove post/comment after you cast the final flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, ios-app, comment-flags

<sub>yes, I know development on the apps is discontinued for the moment. I'm just putting this here in case it gets rolling again in 6-8 years ...</sub>

On the full & mobile website, whenever you flag a post or a comment which causes it to be deleted, it immediately either disappears (in case of a comment) or gets a banner ('this post has been deleted, please refresh the page'). If you cast a final flag in the iOS app, the post or comment stays until you manually refresh the page. Incidentally, the automatic downvote *is* updated in real time, you can see the post score decrease.